# Get access to imported object in component method via eval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, eval

I imported some object from file in vue component. But when i am trying to using it via eval() ive got an error that references is not defined

```
import helper from './somehelperdir'

export default {
    methods: {
        somemethod () {
            console.log(helper) //everithing works great
            eval('helper') //helper is not defined
        }
    }
}
```

Helper returns

```
export default {
    simpleHelpermethod () {
        console.log('Very simple logic') 
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a *really* good reason to use `eval()` - just saying... ([further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil))

Comment: @Utkanos i just think that `eval()` will be looking better then a lot of if : else(switch case)

Comment: What does helper return?

Comment: @A.Llorente there is simplest logic. Updated in question

Comment: Why don't you just execute the function then?

Comment: @A.Llorente i have a lot of helpers with different ends like helperOne, helperTwo etc. And I dont want to use huge switch case constructions

Comment: You can encapsulate switch constructions using objects: https://toddmotto.com/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals/

Comment: @A.Llorente anyway in this case i should to call function as a value of object. And the only way to do this is execute this via `eval()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but why don't you just use helper() ? Or maybe export an object and import in the component only what you need.

import { method1, method2 } from './helpers'

and then something like method1()